# Strange behaviour when using variables

Tags: variables

When I try to use a file name in a variable for the `cs add` command, I cannot understand what happens. I'm using a bash script `myscript.sh` which returns the path name of cscope database (`/mydir/cscope.out`) based on the current file name (`/mydir/myfile.py`):

```
:let db = system("myscript.sh " . expand("%:p"))
```

After that, when I call:

```
:cs add db
```

I get:

```
"E563: stat(/mydir/db) error 2"
```

When I call:

```
:exe "cs add " . db
```

I get:

```
"E563: stat(/mydir/cscope.out^@) error 2"
```

`/mydir/cscope.out` is the right file name which returned by `myscript.sh`, but where the `^@` thing comes from? How do I correctly use the variable with a parameter in this case?

P.S. When `cs add` is called with plain file name:

```
:cs add /mydir/cscope.out
```

Connection is created OK and no errors is reported.

```
:echo db
```

Displays:

```
/mydir/cscope.out

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: `^@` is Ctrl-@, indicating the ASCII NUL character, which shouldn't be there since `system` replaces NULs with SOH (`^A`).

Comment: Not sure, but maybe your script `myscript.sh` includes a new line character at the end of its output. ^@ is the caret notation of a null character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character). You could try getting rid of it like this: `let db=system("myscript.sh " . expand("%:p"))[:-2]` or `let db=substitute(system("myscript.sh " . expand("%:p"), '\n$', '', '')` or `let db=substitute(system("myscript.sh " . expand("%:p"), '[[:cntrl:]]', '', 'g')`. Not tested so I don't know if any of these commands will work in your particular case. Found them here : http://superuser.com/a/935646

Comment: @muru Thanks. The myscript.sh indeed uses -print0 in the 'find' command.

Comment: @saginaw Thanks, your answer solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using GNU `find` for this, then perhaps you can use the `-printf` option:

```
find /some/path -name cscope.out -printf '%p' -quit
```

This will just print the path of the matched file without any additional characters. `-quit` instructs it to exit after the first match. This should avoid the extra NUL and let you use the `:exe` command.

Comment: I use the 'find' for listing files in the project directory tree, which are used for building db (cscope work only with *.c files by default). But 'find' works OK without -print0 as well (-print0 is needed for filenames with \n, as I understand).

Comment: @AlBerger `-print0` is useful if you're handling multiple files in the output, but from what you have said so far, it seems to me the script only outputs one filename.

Comment: Yes, the script outputs the name of the database, but it also rebuilds it when it's connected for the first time (the 'find' is used for rebuilding the database).

Comment: Well, if 'find' is used for rebuilding, then where the \0 comes from? =) I don't know. The file name is outputted with 'echo $dbname'. Anyways, the issue was solved by [:-2]

Comment: @AlBerger then we have a doubly impossible scenario: `echo` isn't going to print a NUL (not like that anyway), and `system` replaces NULs, as I previously noted.